# Django: "order" a queryset based on a boolean field

Tags: django

I want to get all `Menù` instances in this way:

-at the top positions those instances who have `my_boolean_field` set to `True`

-at the last positions those instances that have `my_boolean_field` set to `False`

Here is my `Menù` model and my query:

```
class Menù(models.Model):
    id_menù = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    my_boolean_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# In my View:
my_query_set = Menù.objects.all().order_by('my_boolean_field')
```

I've also searched for a `group_by` option but I didn't find anything in Django ORM

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can add `-` to your  `order_by` query for sort in descending order like this:

```
my_query_set = Menù.objects.all().order_by('-my_boolean_field')  # first get True ones then get False ones
```

another way is add `ordering` to your model `Meta` class like this:

```
class Menù(models.Model):
    id_menù = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    my_boolean_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-my_boolean_field ',)
```

after this change your queries on `my_boolean_field` will be sorted descend by default and not need to use `order_by('-my_boolean_field')`:

```
my_query_set = Menù.objects.all()  # results will be sorted by my_boolean_field in reverse order
```

Comment: You can also mention the `Meta` class `ordering` property in case it should be ordered that way by default.