# Put items on top in django template for loop

Tags: django, for-loop, templates

The model has a field named "is_highlighted", i want to put all items on top if is_highlighted == True when iterate thru the object list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: "order" a queryset based on a boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364691/django-order-a-queryset-based-on-a-boolean-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can give 2 for loops to do this. In first for loop check the condition true.

```
{% for x in list %}
{% if x.is_highlighted == True %}
....
..
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

display others in second for loop

```
{% for x in list %}
{% if x.is_highlighted != True %}
...
...
```

You can also pass 2 query sets through context. I don't know if it's best or any other way. simply this will work.